# JetBrains phpStorm REPEAT Live Template CONTINUOUSLY until user abort (ESC)

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, live-templates

Consider these live template for php array():

**Template- ari**

```
'$KEY1$'=>'$VAL1$',
```

**Template- arr**

```
array(
$REPEAT$
)$ENDS$
```

I introduced a variable $REPEAT$. what I want there is to repeat another defined template CONTINUOUSLY until the user press the ESC key.

Each usage of array template may have different no. of items in it. At one place I have 2 & some other I have 10 items to write.

So for array it should keep repeating: '$KEY1$'=>'$VAL1$', on ENTER key press on $VAL1$

How this can be done using variable expressions or custom implementation?

Right now using it like this:

**Template- arr**

```
array(
'$KEY1$'=>'$VAL1$',
$ENDS$
)
```

Answer (score 4):

PhpStorm live templates do not support such a feature. The only way to achieve this behavior is by writing a custom plugin.